# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve ' ' when trying to run webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I get this error when I try to run webpack but it doesnt really show me what module it cant find. I get this error 4 times in different files. I am starting webpack via commandline with "webpack". I dont see the point

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '' in 'C:\Users\topal\IdeaProjects\cts-abwesendheitstool\cts-abwesendheit-fe'
     @ ./src/index.js 4:0-21
```

This is my code in index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

my webpack config

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.js'),
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: [[
                            '@babel/preset-env', {
                                targets: {
                                    esmodules: true
                                }
                            }],
                            '@babel/preset-react']
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!',
            },
            {
                test: path.join(__dirname, '.'),
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ['@babel/preset-env',
                        '@babel/react', {
                            'plugins': ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']
                        }]
                }
            },
            {test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader'}
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx','.ts', '.tsx'],
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()],
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        hot: true,
    },
};
```

In a different file:

```
import "./App.css";
import Datagrid from "./pages/Datagrid"
import {React, useEffect, useState} from "react";
import * as config from "./config/config";
import DaterangePicker from "./components/DaterangePicker";

function App() {
    const [data,setData]= useState([]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'GET'
        };
        fetch(config.SERVER_URL + `/caldav/getEvents/${config.CALENDAR}`, requestOptions)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then(data => setData(data))
            .catch(error => console.log(error));

    },[data.length]);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                Abwesendheitscheckliste
            </header>
            <DaterangePicker/>
            <Datagrid rows={data}></Datagrid>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

I get the same error:

```
ERROR in ./src/App.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '' in 'C:\Users\topal\IdeaProjects\cts-abwesendheitstool\cts-abwesendheit-fe'
 @ ./src/App.js 2:0-19
 @ ./src/index.js
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try something like this in webpack

> ```
>     use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
> ```